# Poner imagen por encima de un elemento

Tags: html, css

Este es el resultado que llevo hasta ahora:

[image: vista del html]

Tengo como duda cómo sería posible hacer que la imagen esté por encima de la linea que la oculta.

Éste es mi código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.container {
  height: 95vh;
}

.header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(97, 166, 14, .7), rgb(0, 73, 135, .7));
  /*url(img/fondo.jpg);*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 0 100%);
}

.header .logo-box img {
  height: 5vh;
}

.imagen-data .img-data {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.data-planning {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Data Planning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
        <div class="col-4 data-planning">
          <h1>Data Planning</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, totam?.</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Empezemos</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 imagen-data">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="data" class="img-data">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que estás encontrando se debe a que con `clip-path` el `overflow` siempre va a quedar escondido. Por lo que la imagen siempre se va a ver cortada por la línea diagonal.

Para evitar esto puedes optar por varias alternativas:

- Trata de imitar el comportamiento del `clip-path` usando fondos y gradientes (ya tienes uno, pero puedes tener más de uno y se superpondrán). Esto puede ser algo complicado ya que tendrás que jugar un poco con los valores para que quede como quieres.

  ```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
  }

  .container {
    height: 95vh;
  }

  .header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-15deg, white 40%,transparent 40%), linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(97, 166, 14, .7), rgb(0, 73, 135, .7));
    /*url(img/fondo.jpg);*/
    background-size: 100%, cover;
    background-position: top;
  }

  .header .logo-box img {
    height: 5vh;
  }

  .imagen-data .img-data {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .data-planning {
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Data Planning</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
          <div class="col-4 data-planning">
            <h1>Data Planning</h1>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, totam?.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Empezemos</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 imagen-data">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="data" class="img-data">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```
- Usa pseudo-elementos para poner el fondo que quieres y recortarlo. De este modo, el contenido del `header` no se verá cortado por el `clip-path`.

  ```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
  }

  .container {
    height: 95vh;
  }

  .header {
    /*url(img/fondo.jpg);*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    position: relative;
  }

  .header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 0 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(97, 166, 14, .7), rgb(0, 73, 135, .7));
  }

  .header .logo-box img {
    height: 5vh;
  }

  .imagen-data .img-data {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .data-planning {
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Data Planning</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
          <div class="col-4 data-planning">
            <h1>Data Planning</h1>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, totam?.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Empezemos</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8 imagen-data">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="data" class="img-data">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Deberías usar el propiedad CSS `z-index` la cual recibe como valor un número que a mayor valor entonces colocará a este elemento por encima de su predecesor; es decir:

El div:

```
.imagen-data{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Lo anterior provocará se vea por encima del div que contiene el `h1` que dice *Data Planning*

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema porque realmente el usuario está usando clip-path para cortar la cabecera. Cambiar el z-index de la imagen (o su contenedor), no hará que quede por encima de la línea cortada.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, pase por alto ese detalle